# Removing redundant queries using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

The following code works, but runs far too many SQL statements for my liking;

```
User.includes([:profile,:roles]).select("id, email, created_at, confirmed_at, countries.name").find_in_batches do |users| 
        users.map{|u| # In here I access profile.country.name} 
end
```

What is meant to do is grab the User information along with some profile information and put it into a csv format.

Inside the `.map` I am calling `profile.country.name` this is coming in fine but Rails is running an extra SQL call to find the name, what I want to do is capture this information in my initial lookup.

My issue is that because `country` is linked to `profile` and not `user` I can't add it to my `.includes` because it doesn't see it as a linkable table. Is there anything I can do to force the includes to join a table linked to `profile`?

The relevant model information is below;

User:

```
has_one  :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

Profile:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :country
```

Country:

```
has_many :profiles
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to include country in the original query by nesting it under profile in the .includes call:

```
User.includes( {:profile => [:country], :roles} )
```

Comment: Cheers Barry, I had to play some more with the [] to make it work: `includes(:profile => [:country], :roles => [])`

Comment: Ah yes, of course I forgot that it must become a hash rather than an array to allow key => value notation.